# Conductive ball submerged in electric field

Tags: physics, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I have a question about well-posedness of the following problem. First, I'll demonstrate the problem on an example, but in general, I'd say it's a grossly over-defined BVP: $\nabla^2 \varphi = 0$ outside of a bounded region of space (i.e. outside of a ball, cylinder, ... potato, ...) with $\vec{\nabla} \varphi = \vec{F}$ in the limit of being far away from the origin (far away from that bounded region of space) and $\vec{n} \times \vec{\nabla} \varphi = \vec{0}$ when at the boundary of an object, with $\vec{n}$ being the normal vector of the surface of the object (almost looks like a Neumann problem, over-defined by one dimension).

Here's an example when "object" = ball. Let's have a perfectly conductive ball of radius $R$ sitting at the origin. We turn on the electric field, which, far away from the ball, is of the form $\vec{E} = E_0 \hat{z}$ (uniform field for simplicity pointing in the $z$-direction). How is the electric field deformed near the sphere?

Now I'm familiar with the solution and it is indeed possible to write down both electric field and potential outside explicitly
$$
\vec{E} (r,\theta) = E_0 \left( 1 + \frac{2 R^3}{r^3} \right) \cos \theta \, \hat{r} - E_0 \left( 1 - \frac{R^3}{r^3} \right) \sin \theta \, \hat{\theta} = E_0 \left[ \left( 1 - \frac{R^3}{r^3} \right) \hat{z} + \frac{3 r^3 z}{r^4} \hat{r} \right]
$$
where hat vectors are unit vectors in the corresponding direction.

The way to derive this is to exploit that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = 0$ (Faraday), therefore $\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} \varphi$ and since there's no charges, from Gauss' law we have $\nabla^2 \varphi = 0$ in the region outside of the sphere. Then we write down the most general function that satisfies $\nabla^2 \varphi = 0$ in spherical coordinates with azimuthal symmetry
$$
\varphi (r, \theta) = \sum_{\ell = 0}^\infty \left( \alpha_\ell r^\ell + \frac{\beta_\ell}{r^{\ell+1}} \right) P_\ell (\cos \theta)
$$
where $P_\ell$ are Legendre polynomials. Considering that far away from the sphere the field has the form $\vec{E} = E_0 \hat{z} = E_0 \left( \cos \theta \, \hat{r} - \sin \theta \, \hat{\theta} \right)$, we right away pick $\ell = 1$ and $\alpha_1 = - E_0$. Then by imposing $\hat{\theta} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ at the boundary of the sphere, we restrict the solution further by $B_1 = E_0 R^3$.

Now, my question is: this is obviously neither a Dirichlet nor Neumann problem. Firstly, we are somehow able to impose the full gradient of $\varphi$ at $r \to \infty$ (which is the "outer" boundary of our region). This almost seems like a Neumann problem, but with Neumann problem we can only prescribe $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \varphi$. Secondly, at the boundary of the sphere we again prescribe a very weird boundary condition: $\vec{t}_{1,2} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \varphi = 0$ where $\vec{t}_{1,2}$ is the basis of tangential space ot the sphere. This can also be written as $\hat{r} \times \vec{\nabla} \varphi = \vec{0}$ where $\hat{r}$ serves as the normal vector at the surface of the sphere. Therefore, we are somehow able to prescribe more than we should be able to, yet everything in the end works out smoothly and we get a unique solution (there's a question mark here, because uniqueness wasn't proved - not that I'm aware of any other function that would satisfy these conditions).

**What kind of problem is this?** It cannot be either Dirichlet or Neumann problem, but do mathematicians recognize this kind of BVP and give it a name? Can we take an object of arbitrary shape and pose the same problem for it? How would you prove existence and uniqueness of the solution (does it always exist and is it unique)? Just to be clear, we're solving Laplace equation $\nabla^2 \varphi = 0$ outside of a bounded conductive object with $\varphi \to - E_0 z$ when far away from said object and $\vec{n} \times \vec{\nabla} \varphi = \vec{0}$ at the surface of the object, where $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector of the surface. If this problem isn't well defined, i.e. there are objects for which the solution does not exist or exists but is not unique, I would very much like to see a counterexample (so I can nag someone with a CNC to make me such object and do an experiment).

**Can we generalize the kind of field we submerge the object into?** Can we say the background field is of the form $\vec{E} = E_x (x,y,z) \hat{x} + E_y (x,y,z) \hat{y} + E_z (x,y,z) \hat{z}$ (of course, it must be irrotational, so that we're still in the realm of electrostatics)? I'm asking this because the boundary condition of the original problem, $\vec{E} = E_0 \hat{z}$ seems almost like the sophomore's dream: the field far away is already in the shape that is one of the Legendre polynomials, i.e. it seems like this problem was naturally set up to be solved this way, but can we modify the background field so it's not so easy?

Comment: If I understand your question, you seem to imply that Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions should not coexist in such problems, which you refer to as "over-defined". But electromagnetism problems are full of fields that twist and turn at different points in space because the boundary conditions change. The two you described are boundaries at different locations in space and there is no overlap or contradiction. Indeed, evenCauchy (or Robin) boundary conditions are thought of formally as mixtures of Dirichlet and Neumann conditions. I am not sure why you see this problem as as unnatural.

Comment: @user135626 first of all, you seem to have misunderstood what this question was about. I'm not saying that mixing Dirichlet and Neumann conditions on different parts of the boundary is over defining the problem. In fact, Robin condition covers all that. What I'm saying is that defining too much on the SAME part of the boundary is over-defining. I'm sure you would agree that you cannot define both $\phi$ and $\partial_n \phi$ at the same part of the boundary, that problem might not have a solution. Thus, I was wondering, how one can define $\vec{n} \times \vec{\nabla} \phi$.

Comment: @user135626 so what condition $\vec{n} \times \vec{\nabla} \phi = \vec{0}$ on the boundary is? Dirichlet, Neumann or Robin?

Comment: If I understand your description and notation correctly, then $\hat{n}\times\vec{\nabla}\phi=0$ is equivalent to $\hat{n}\times\vec{E}=0$ on the conductive surface of the ball, which is a vector form of saying that the tangential $E$ field must vanish on the surface and the surface is equipotential surface ($\phi$ constant); i.e. the usual Dirichlet condition.

Comment: @user135626 that is true, but that constant is not specified. Also, what condition is $\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} \phi = E_0 \hat{z}$ at infinity? That is specifying two components of the gradient...

Comment: Some thoughts: The potential far from the sphere must obey Laplace's equation if we insist there is no free charge far away, thus we naturally get 'convenient' asymptotic forms proportional to eg. $r\cos\theta$ or $r^2 P_2( \cos \theta)$. Attempting to specify an inconvenient field far away, such as $r^2 \cos\theta$ would violate Laplace's equation for large $r$. As for the $E$ field, would you be happier with the problem if we only specified $V$ for large $r$ and not $E$?

Comment: As I mentioned, near the ball it is the usual Dirichlet condition ($\phi$ constant). The exact value of that constant (depending on any charge on the ball surface) does not affect the fact that it is Dirichlet type. Your other question about the $z$ directed $E$ field at infinity is an idealization that implies that at infinity there is some transverse plane charge (parallel to $xy$ plane) that is Dirichlet boundary, forcing the $x, y$ components of $E$ to vanish and $z$ component to hold.